# Count all occurences of each element in a list

Tags: haskell, count, counting

How do I efficiently count all occurences of each element in a list? I thought of using an associative list or some hash map, but immutability gets in the way and it's not evidently clear how an (hopefully) elegant solution should arise.

The signature could be like this:

```
countOccurences :: [a] -> [(a, Int)]
```

Example:

```
countOccurences [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4]
```

results in

```
[(1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1), (4, 1)]
```

(order is not important though).

Comment: How does immutability get in the way? Just use an immutable hash map.

Comment: The OP is probably asking how to write an O(n) implementation. Most immutable hash maps have o(1) lookup and insertion operations. (`Data.IntMap` comes close to O(1), as in practice you probably don't have arbitrarily large counts to deal with.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`group . sort` will produce an output list such as

```
> group . sort $ [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4] 
[[1,1,1],[2,2],[3],[4]]
```

Hence,

```
> map (head &&& length) . group . sort $ [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4] 
[(1,3),(2,2),(3,1),(4,1)]
```

So, we obtain

```
import Data.List (group, sort)
import Control.Arrow ((&&&))

countOccurences :: Ord a => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
countOccurences = map (head &&& length) . group . sort
```

It should require only `O(n log n)` time.

Answer (score 6):

Since chi provided a solution using `group . sort`, here is one that uses [`Data.Map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html):

```
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M
import           Data.Map.Strict (Map)

histogram :: Ord a => [a] -> Map a Int
histogram = M.fromListWith (+) . (`zip` [1,1..])
```

This also uses *O(n log n)* time.

> I thought of using an associative list or some hash map, but immutability gets in the way

`Data.Map` is a tree-based associative map, so maybe this representation is for you.

If you'd rather like an `[(a, Int)]`, `M.assocs` can convert the `Data.Map` back:

```
countOccurrences :: Ord a => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
countOccurrences = M.assocs . histogram
```

Comment: or `histogram = foldl' (\m k -> M.insertWith (+) k 1 m) M.empty`, to eliminate the need for `zip`.

Comment: Or `Data.HashMap`, or `Data.IntMap`. Whichever you choose, use the strict operations: `import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M`.

Comment: @dfeuer: Thanks, I've updated it to `Data.Map.Strict`.